# Ubuntu 22.04 Memory Leak

Tags: ram, memory-leak

Over the course of a few days, I see the RAM Memory usage keeps going up and up. For example, I have 32 GB of RAM. System Monitor shows over 27 GB used, but when I look at Processes there is way less than 10 GB accounted for. Brave is about 3 GB. If I close Brave, System Monitor goes down about 100 MB, still showing about 27 GB being used. I let it go, eventually Ubuntu will crash.

Comment: what makes you say that eventually ubuntu will crash? what sort of crash info did you get out of the machine previously, if there was a previous crash? what do the monitoring tools report as memory using processes? I'd suggest digging into tools like 'vmstat' and 'free'; top can be useful, but it often masks what's really going on. I suspect your system is, like most linux based systems, trying to use all available memory as IO caching, disk or network buffering... something. as nature abhors a vacuum, linux abhors unused memory.

Comment: Could you please provide us a screenshot of your system monitor resources usage and the output of `free -h` in a terminal?

Comment: If you can identify the cause of the leak, then please file an appropriate bug report. AskUbuntu is not the bug tracker.

Comment: "Crash" means the system resets. It appears the problem is buff/cache. It doesn't seem to go down by itself. I found some links that pointed me to:   #  sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches    This clears the cache and all seems to be good.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue on a 4GB SBC system, so I notice it immediately.  The percentage of shared memory continues to raise while general memory percentage drops until applications begin to swap and at some point ground to halt.  Only a reboot will free the shared memory!

Comment: $ free -h
                      total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            31Gi        20Gi       470Mi       1.0Gi        10Gi       9.3Gi
Swap:             0B          0B          0B

Comment: Believe I am seeing something similar. Thought it was a Firefox problem. But even when Firefox closed, swap memory still shows higher than expected usage on no user apps running. Ram has a couple of GB free at this time. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1460651/why-is-firefox-eating-up-swap-on-ubuntu-22-04

Comment: I have this issue with Ubuntu Studio 22.04.2. Closing applications does release RAM, except when I fall asleep to videos (played in SMPlayer, if that heps). When the video ends, the screen shuts off (but it's not set to suspend session). When I wake up, another GB of RAM is in use, even after quitting applications. The next day, more RAM is in use, and the next, etc., until the computer slows to a crawl and I have to reboot. I don't have this problem with Kubuntu 20.04 on the same computer. Device is triple-boot and uses legacy BIOS. As with OP, System Monitor doesn't account for the used RAM.